# Get Dropdown Text Given Value

Tags: jquery, ajax, text, drop-down-menu

I have an Ajax call that will return the value of the drop down. I want to use this value to get the text to populate a table.

What would be the correct syntax for:

```
var dropDownText = $("#dropDownId").SelectedValue[valueFromAjax].Text
```

So that `dropDownText` will contain a string that corresponds to the value in the drop down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work

```
$("#dropDownId option[value='" + valueFromAjax + "']").text();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/YeASm/